# How do I set a dynamic model attribute in the fixture?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

As the title describes, I am running into trouble making a dynamic attribute on the Fixture layer.

Here is an example model:

```
App.Pokeball = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    ballRate: DS.attr('number'),
    battleAttributes: DS.belongsTo('battleAttributes')
});
```

And my Fixture:

```
App.Pokeball.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES : [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'PokeBall',
            ballRate: 1
        },
        {
            id: 23,
            name: 'Dusk Ball',
            ballRate: function() {
                // Some logic that applies only model #23
                return 2;
            }.property('battleAttributes')
        }
    ]
});
```

I scoured online trying to find out the right way to do this, but have instead ran into a dead end. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an invalid use of fixtures. They’re meant to represent JSON (or whatever) on the server that is passed to your application and turned into Ember Data models. JSON cannot represent the concept of a computed property, it’s for pure data.

I don’t understand your use case so I could be way off, it seems like you should use a computed property on the model instead:

```
App.Pokeball = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  ballRate: DS.attr('number'),
  battleAttributes: DS.belongsTo('battleAttributes'),

  adjustedBallRate: function() {
    if (this.get('battleAttributes.whateverPropertyCausesThisToChange') == 'special value') {
      return 2;
    }
    else {
      return this.get('ballRate');
    }
  }.property('battleAttributes.whateverPropertyCausesThisToChange')
});
```

Comment: Part of my issue is that the adjustedBallRate will be different for different models, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/eLq734y8/

Comment: You have to find a way to express these attributes by composing simple attributes. You can’t pass computed properties across the wire like that.

Comment: Is there a recommended way to pass Controller variables to the model on a case-by-case basis? I could do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/6m2ysauj/ ... but that feels incredibly hacky :(

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your data model. It seems like all the data is known in advance, you shouldn’t need controllers to be reaching into models and setting properties like that. Maybe you need attributes like `caveBallRate`, `nonCaveBallRate`, 'firstTurnBallRate`, et cetera, that are combined. Or maybe you need to further decompose the data model.

Comment: Well, if you have a minute, this is what I got: https://github.com/TheIronDeveloper/pokemon-catch-rate/blob/master/scripts/app.js

The PokemonModel will maintain data about pokemon (all the data can be set with e Fixture), the PokeballModel represents 25 Pokeballs that display a % catch rate. The BattleAttributes was going to contain each of the boolean values that may alter some of the Pokeball models...

Comment: (Demo here: theirondeveloper.github.io/pokemon-catch-rate )

Comment: If whether the Pokeball is in a cave affects each type of Pokeball differently, it’s an attribute of a Pokeball. My suggestion of `caveBallRate` and `nonCaveBallRate` is unwieldy and maybe there’s another way, but I can’t think on this further hehe

Comment: Though if all your data is available in advance and never changes, it seems weird to use Ember Data at all. And I highly recommend you switch to using Ember CLI, it’s the future of Ember applications, and quite excellent.